# Tkinter: How do I create an entry box that highlights as a user hovers their mouse over it?

Tags: python, tkinter, tk-toolkit, ttk

In Tkinter, I would like to create an Entry box that highlights when the user hovers their mouse over it. I have tried the code below but unfortunately it hasn't worked; the entry box only highlights when I click on it.

```
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.ttk as ttk


class App(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        entry_style = ttk.Style()
        entry_style.map('TEntry', highlightcolor=[("active", "green")])
        entry = ttk.Entry(self)
        entry.pack()


app = App()
app.mainloop()
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You need to use `<Enter>` and `<Leave>` [binds](https://effbot.org/tkinterbook/tkinter-events-and-bindings.htm) to achieve something like that.

Comment: Try `entry_style.map('TEntry', lightcolor=[("hover", "green"), ("focus", "green")])`. Also note that not all theme let you modify such color.  It works for me when using theme `clam`.

Answer (score 1):

If you are not set into using `ttk`, the plain `tk`approach is to bind the events `'<Enter>'` and `'<Leave>'` to a configuration setting:

```
import tkinter as tk


class App(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        entry = tk.Entry(self)
        entry.pack()
        entry.bind('<Enter>', lambda dummy_event: entry.config(bg='green'))
        entry.bind('<Leave>', lambda dummy_event: entry.config(bg='white'))

app = App()
app.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

The aqua theme is very rigid and does not allow changes to its theme.